# Visualize text classes in a scatter-plot

Tags: python, nlp, text-classification, torch

I am looking for ways to investigate in my train data 'modellability' and check if the classes are well distinguished in terms of vocabulary... etc.

I am a bit embarrassed but I was wondering if it is possible to do a scatter plot for text classification model in torch? or any other approach to investigate in the data quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dimensionality reduction (PCA, t-SNE or UMAP) + a color hue to inspect your data. I recommend using bokeh to interactively look at your data even though here I'll show you with seaborn.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import umap
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits()

embedding = umap.UMAP().fit_transform(digits.data)  # 2D embedding

sns.scatterplot(x=embedding[:,0], y=embedding[:,1], hue=digits.target)
```

[image]